# can messages templates for WhatsApp include quick reply buttons in Twilio

Tags: node.js, twilio, whatsapp

Using Twilio and Regarding the WhatsApp template messages sent form the system or even the normal messages sent by the chat bot, can it include quick reply buttons like Yes/No buttons or customized options like options (1, 2, 3)

Is it doable? any available samples?

Comment: I've just updated my answer, Twilio does now support quick reply buttons. Check the links in my answer for further detail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit**

The [Twilio API for WhatsApp now supports interactive message templates](https://www.twilio.com/blog/using-whatsapp-quick-reply-buttons-for-more-engaging-customer-experiences). Check out [the documentation for using buttons in WhatsApp templates here](https://www.twilio.com/docs/whatsapp/buttons).

---

Twilio developer evangelist here.

Currently you cannot send interactive messages with quick reply buttons using the Twilio API for WhatsApp. That may change in the future though. If you have set up your WhatsApp number and you were in touch with an account executive, I recommend speaking with them.

Comment: Awesome, if it was helpful would you mind marking the answer as correct? It helps others who come across this too. Thanks!